# Cannot Find Module 'blueBird-lst' in Electron.js

Tags: javascript, angular, electron, bluebird

Everytime that I close my app, it is still running but hidden (I see it when I  open the task manager and see the process is still running), and when I double click to open the app again, that's when the error shows and closes the app.

"Uncaught exception:
Error: Cannot find Module 'bluebird-lst'"

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure to close the app when closing your last window.

In your main.js, add something like that:

```
mainWindow.on("closed", function () {
    mainWindow = null;
    app.quit();
})
```